# Find on remote and rsync find results to a local directory

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

```
ssh user@remote find /var/ -type f -name \*option\*  -print0 | xargs -J d11:% -0 rsync -aP % oo/.
```

As you can see, i am running find on remote, getting the list of files, and now i am trying to copy them over; the second part of my command, after the pipeline seems incorrect.

Comment: Can you give us an example ? ... I cant recreate the first command without having problems with user rights. Then `xargs` reads the standard input, delimited by whitespaces, this could make some trouble too. Last but not least I dont get the `%` and `oo/.`  thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your command seems off a bit. The -J and d11:% options I can't find a reference for plus your rsync cmd needs a destination. Here is my attempt at your command.
"ssh user@remote find /folder/ -type f -name '*option*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I% rsync -aP % dest_machine:/path"